# Laravel 4: Oracle Connection is failing suddenly

Tags: php, oracle11g, laravel-4, oracle-call-interface

I have a Laravel 4 website on my localhost and i was using Oracle database.
I tested it perfectly for weeks, no problem occured.
Suddenly when it started giving the error: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

[image]

In my app/config/database.php i have,

```
'oracle' => array(
        'driver' => 'pdo-via-oci8',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '1521',
        'database' => 'orcl', //xe Service ID
        'username' => 'system', //schema
        'password' => '123',
        'charset' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
    ),
```

My SQL PLUS and Sql Developer is running fine with the same username-password.
Please help .

Answer (score 1):

Try ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;